# MongoDb : Copy a field using update and $set

Tags: mongodb

I'm using Mongo version 4.4.7. And i trying to copy a field in other field :

```
db.getCollection('UserAccount').update(
         { }, 
         { $set:  {'Profile.Email' : '$UserName'}}, 
         false,  
         true 
)

// Result Profile.Email : "$UserName" 
// I want Profile.Email : "myemail@myemail.com"
```

Mongo copy the string "$UserName" and not the value of this variable.

But when i execute aggregate it's work perfectly, But in my case i want an **update** :

```
db.getCollection('UserAccount').aggregate( [
         
    {$set: {'Profile.Email' : '$UserName'} }
    
])
```

Any idea of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an aggregation into an update using `[]` (check [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) link) like this:

```
db.collection.update({},
[  <-- Start aggregation
  {
    "$set": {
      "Profile.Email": "$UserName"
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TgrH5oXGpO4)